# Android connecting to MySQL json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to get data from MySQL database but in the php file I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: json_encode() in /homez.100/pizzapar/www/clic/marwa/test/base.php on line 13
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php     
echo"welcom <br>"; 
$conn =  mysql_connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx','xxx','xxx');

if ($conn) {

    mysql_select_db('zak', $conn);


    $sql=mysql_query("select * from zak_user");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
  $output[]=$row;
  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();

    }
else 
{
echo"erreur connexion";
}
```

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://fr.php.net/json_encode) used to be not part of PHP, you might have to compile an extension to enable this function.

It's been awhile that json_encode is shipped with PHP(since 5.2), I advise you to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/json_encode), `json_encode()` is available in PHP >= 5.2.0 only. You are probably running an older version.

Comment: @manita no problem. If at all possible, upgrading to PHP 5.2 would be the best way to go

Comment: i did thanks and it works but in the emulator it show me an error JSONObject must begin with '{' or my result in the php is an array [{..},... {..}] any help about that?

Answer (score 1):

See here:
http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

This is a replacement for JSON in earlier PHP versions.

Usage:

```
require 'jsonwrapper.php';
```

> At the top of your code and you're ready to go. Of course,
>   jsonwrapper.php must be in the same folder. If not, adjust the require
>   command.
>
> json_encode example
>
> Just to give you a sense of the possibilities:

```
$data = array(
array('name' => 'Jane', 'age' => 35),
array('name' => 'Steve', 'age' => 37)
);
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
</script>
```

And this is the direct download:
http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.tar.gz